# Probleme with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need help with my project,  i have to do an 'drag n drop' zone, and, when the image is droped, it must be saved on the server (via PHP, which I succeeded), but also appear on the HTML thanks to the response from AJAX via PHP. I don't know what to do anymore, here is some code bugs. Each time I see the JS alert announces: 'An exception is produced: undefined'. I don't use Jquery or anyting else, it's just vanilla PHP and Javascript, Thanks for your help

Sorry for my bad English, I'm french :)

my code :

```
<body onload="init()" >
<div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">
    <div id="drag_upload_file">
        <p>Drop file here</p>
        <p>or</p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();"></p>
        <input type="file" id="selectfile">
        
        
    </div>
</div> <br>
<img id = "imageSource" src="uploads/"/>
 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fileobj;
    
    var url = "ajax.php";
    


    function upload_file(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var target = document.getElementById ("drop_file_zone");

            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
              var fileobj = event.dataTransfer.files[i];
              ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
            }}
            
     function file_explorer() {
         document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
         document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
             fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[0];
             ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
         };
     }

     function init() {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var x = document.getElementById("imageSource");
    }

    function prepareData() {

        let url = "ajax.php";
        makeRequest( url, fileobj );
    }

     function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
        
             request.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
             var formData = new FormData();
             formData.append('file', file_obj);
             request.open('POST', url)
             request.send(formData)
      
            }

            
    function alertContents() {
        try {
            if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (request.status === 200) {

                    var reponse = JSON.parse( request.reponseText);
                    x.setAttribute("src", 'uploads' + reponse.text);
                   
                   //document.getElementById("imageSource").src = reponse.text;
                } else {
                    alert("Un problème est survenu au cours de la requête.");
            }
        }
        }
        catch( e ) {
            alert("Une exception s’est produite : " + event.description);
        }
    }

        
     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my PHP

```
<?php
```

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name']);

$test = '{ "text":"uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'"}';
echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ;

Comment: What is `request`? Don't use global variables.

Comment: request = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: Sure, inside `init()` function it's an `XMLHttpRequest`. But not anywhere else. Variables should be passed from function to function. If you want to rely on global variables, **which you should not**, you need to create them in the global scope before using them.